# yii2 testing using codeception

Tags: php, testing, yii2, testcase, codeception

I am writing a simple test case. I installed codeception using composer.
My test cases are located in root folder inside test case folder

when i try to run the following code

```
namespace app\tests\testcases;

use yii\codeception\TestCase;

class SomeMyTest extends TestCase
{

public function testOne()
{
    echo "here";
}



}
```

when i try to run the code in a browser i get the following error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'yii\codeception\TestCase' not found
```

There is this file called as yiisoft\yii2-codeception\TestCase.php in my project

What am i doing wrong? Can anyone help.?

Comment: I followed instruction given in [link]https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/tree/master/tests[/link]. 
 I get the following error.
  [Codeception\Exception\Configuration]
  Configuration file could not be found.
  Run `bootstrap` to initialize Codeception.



build [-c|--config[="..."]]

Comment: Do we need to add any settings to config file of yii ton use te test feature?

Comment: I feel its something to do with the configuration file. Did anyone used this before?

Comment: Did you run the "codecept bootstrap" command?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-codeception

```sh
composer require yiisoft/yii2-codeception --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Install codeception using this commands

```
composer require codeception/codeception
composer require codeception/specify
composer require codeception/verify
```

More at https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/test-environment-setup